# Кулдаун в телеграм боте через базу данных

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3, python-telegram-bot

Хочу сделать вывод сообщения при кулдауне по типу "Осталось подождать ЧАСОВ:МИНУТ", как сделать такой формат - не знаю.

```py
import telebot
import sqlite3
import datetime
from imports import *

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
cur = conn.cursor()


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    last_command_use_time = cur.execute('SELECT get_card_cd FROM users WHERE user_id={}'.format(message.chat.id)).fetchone()[0]
    conn.commit()
    p = list(itertools.accumulate([0.01, 0.005, 0.015, 0.05, 0.07, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.4]))
    n = bisect.bisect(p, random.random())
    x = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_command_use_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    print(type(last_command_use_time), last_command_use_time)

    user_id = message.chat.id

    if not last_command_use_time or (datetime.datetime.now() - x).seconds/14400 > 1:
        cur.execute('UPDATE users SET get_card_cd =? WHERE user_id =?', (datetime.datetime.now(), user_id))
        conn.commit()
        if n == 0:
            print("1%")
            bot.send_message()
        elif n == 1:
            print("0,5%")
        elif n == 2:
            print("1,5%")
        elif n == 3:
            print("5%")
        elif n == 4:
            print("7%")
        elif n == 5:
            print("10%")
        elif n == 6:
            print("15%")
        elif n == 7:
            print("20%")
        elif n == 8:
            print("40%")
        else:
            print('Error')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Осталось подождать времени')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде описана команда `/go`

Команда реагирует на её активацию пользователем, и записывает в строку с пользователем дату и время нажатия.

Если не прошёл час после прошлого нажатия, то говорим, чтобы ждали.

В [sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3) уже должна быть строка с пользователем.

```py
import telebot
import sqlite3
import datetime


bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

sql = sqlite3.connect('FILE')
conn = sql.cursor()

@bot.message_handler(commands=["go"])
def go(message):
    last_command_use_time = conn.execute('SELECT go FROM users WHERE id={}'.format(message.chat.id)).fetchone()[0]
    
    if not last_command_use_time or (datetime.datetime.now() - last_command_use_time).hour > 1:
        # Если кнопка не нажималась или с прошлого запуска команды прошёл час
            conn.execute('UPDATE users SET go={} WHERE id={}'.format(datetime.datetime.now(),message.chat.id))
            sql.commit()
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Нужное сообщение...')
    else:
        # Если же час ещё не прошёл
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Подождите!')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: а можно как то сделать чтобы по вводу команды говорилось "Осталось подождать n времени"?

Comment: Указываем в Подождите:
seconds = (datetime.datetime.now() - last_command_use_time).seconds
minutes = datetime.timedelta(minutes=seconds)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Осталось подождать {} времени'.format(minutes))

Comment: если честно, то не очень понял